# How to Automate Random Security Questions using Selenium or UFT14?

Tags: java, selenium, vbscript, uft14

I am working on a testing project to develop an automated test suite for a banking web app. The "Reset Password" functionality has the security questions feature to identify the end-user. The text and answer field (textbox, dropdowns, etc) of the same question changes randomly. I talked to the Developer, and he has shared the set of questions that can be asked the customer.

I am looking for a solution to handle these scenarios. Spying each question and then take decisions using a lot of if-else/switch-case blocks makes the code very complex and less readable.

I have now the freedom to use either selenium or UFT. Your support will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: VBScript for a "Banking Web App"? Which Bank is it, so I know not to use their services?

Comment: Obviously not! Client is using UFT for test automation. Hence, I need to use VBScript as the programming language. If now you'd like to help?

Comment: Is your intent to test this password reset process or to just get through it and get on to the real test? Also, please post the questions and how each is different (textbox vs dropdowns, etc.). This info will be important in coming up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Different ways to handle the above scenario(Just kind of rough idea):**

1. Keep the question and answers in an external file:

   If the Security questions set is big, you can keep all the questions in an external
   test data file, say excel file.

   Each row of excel should have a question in the first column and answer in the next
   columns. So you can check in which row the question is there and fetch the
   corresponding answer(Some like this as per your scenario)
2. Use Hashmap inside an Hashmap(based on how many answers> to store this data or you
   can create an json file structure for all the data and fetch accordingly

Regarding to the tool, it has many criteria's to choose the tool/programming language.

Comment: So you're going to have an Excel sheet for each customer/account?

Comment: It can follow the same way, how the other test testdata like customer/account credentials etc will be maintained. This might not be the exact way or solution as the question is subjective, but some rough idea.